# Module already installed but python program is still telling me to install

Tags: python

```
nandos@joseph:~$ pip3 install colorama pysnmp
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pysnmp in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.4.11)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pysnmp) (3.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.2.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pysnmp) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pysmi in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pysnmp) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ply in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pysmi->pysnmp) (3.11)
nandos@joseph:~$ pip3 install win_unicode_console
Requirement already satisfied: win_unicode_console in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5)
nandos@joseph:~$ '/home/nandos/Downloads/PRET-master/pret.py' 
Please install the 'colorama' module for color support.
Please install the 'pysnmp' module for SNMP support.

usage: pret.py [-h] [-s] [-q] [-d] [-i file] [-o file] target {ps,pjl,pcl}
pret.py: error: too few arguments
```

Comment: You sure this is a Python 3 app and not Python 2?

Comment: Is python3 not a python2 interpreter?

Comment: no it is not, Python 2 and Python 3 are fundamentally different, Py2 code is not necessarily Python 3 compatible and vice versa.  Show the output of `head -n 1 /home/nandos/Downloads/PRET-master/pret.py` please, that should let us know if it's a py2 or py3 program

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `head -n 1` on your python application indicates it's a Python 2 application.

You have installed the Python 3 versions of the specified libraries, but not the Python 2 versions.  Python 2 and Python 3 interpreters are **different** and you need to make sure you install the proper libs for the proper interpreters.

Install Python 2 and its corresponding `pip` if it's not already installed, then install the corresponding Python modules you need:

```
sudo apt install python-all python-pip
pip install colorama pysnmp
```

Then run your application.  Provided that this runs properly, it should 'just work' now provided you actually provide proper arguments to the program to do things as it indicates in the last line of its error message.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just installed python 2 and it seems to work now.

Comment: Great!  If this answer helped you and helped solve the problem, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted so that the question is marked as 'solved'!